# How can I prevent trailing periods in number inputs?

Tags: html, validation, input, validity.js

I have the following HTML that prevents everything to be entered in a number search field, except for an ending period:

```html
<input type="number" id="DrawingNumber" min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" />
```

For example, I can enter "1." or "111." etc. I would like it to prevent me from entering the ending period. It prevents me from entering everything else, such as leading zeroes, symbols, letters, except for the ending period.

Comment: try setting `step=1`

Comment: It still allows entering a trailing period. When I check the payload of what value was passed to search, it is the number without the trailing period. I would just like to prevent it from being entered.

Comment: Then your only other option is to catch the key down event and cancel it on `.` seems everything else is handled afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<input type="number" id="DrawingNumber" 
       min="1" 
       onkeypress="return /\d/i.test(event.key)"
       oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" />
```